# C# locks and newbie multithreading questions

Tags: c#, multithreading

Some newbie questions about multi-threading in .NET which I think will help reinforce some concepts I'm trying to absorb - I've read several multi-threading material (including the Albahari ebook) but feel I just need some confirmation of some questions to help drive these concepts home

1. A lock scope protects a shared region of code - suppose there is a thread executing a method that increments a simple integer variable x in a loop - however this won't protect code elsewhere that might also alter variable x eg in another method on another thread ...

   Since this is two different regions of code potentially affecting the same variable, do we solve this by locking both regions of code using the same lock variable for both lock scopes around variable x?  If you locked both regions of code with different lock variables, this would not protect the variable correct?
2. To further this example, using the same lock variable, what would happen if for some reason, code in one method went into some infinite loop and never relinquished the lock variable - how could the second region of code in the other method detect this?
3. How does the choice of lock variable influence the behavior of the lock? I've read numerous posts on this subject already but can never seem to find a definitive answer - in some instances people explicitly use an object variable specifically for this purpose, other times people use lock(this) and finally there've been times I've seen people use a type object.

   How do the different choices of lock variables influence the behavior / scope of the lock and what scenarios would it make sense to use one over the other?
4. suppose you have a hashtable wrapped in a class exposing add, remove, get and some sort of Calculate method (say each object represents a quantity and this method sums each value) and all these methods are locked - however, once a reference to an object in that collection is made available to other code and passed around an application, this object (not the hashtable) would now be outside the lock scope surrounding the methods of that class ..how could you then protect access / updates to those actual objects taken from the hashtable, which could interfere with the Calculate method?

Appreciate any heuristics provided that would help reinforce these concepts for me - thanks!

Comment: One question per question, please.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - normally yes, but this is a series of (strongly) related questions.

Comment: Please don't close this. This question is useful and has useful answers. The sub-questions belong together.

Comment: @usr: that's not how [so] works. OP should ask separate questions, and include links to all of them, if he likes, but they need to be separate questions. This is not a discussion forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)
You are correct. You must use the same lock object to protect two distinct area's of code that for example increment the variable x.

2)
This is known as a deadlock and is one of the difficulties with multithreaded programming. There are algorithms which can be used to prevent deadlocks such as the Bankers Algorithm.

3)
Some languages make locking easy, for example in .Net you can just create an object and use it as the shared lock. This is good for synchronising code within a given process. Lock(this) just applies the lock to the object in question. However try to avoid this, instead create a private object and use that. Lock(this) can lead to deadlocking situations. The lock object underneath is probably just a wrapper around a Critical Section. If you wanted to protect a resource across different processes you would need a much heavier named Mutex, this requires a lock on a kernel object and is expensive, so do not use unless you must.

4)You need to make sure locking is applied there as well. But surely when people call methods on this reference they call the methods which employ synchronisation.

Comment: Problem is, if the Get method returns a reference / pointer to an arbitrary object inside the underlying collection (eg an instance of an Object class in .NET), how could you protect this object once a reference to it is returned by the class which encapsulates the collection storing the object, but not the object itself eg once a reference is returned from the synchronized Get method and passed around the application to other thread-unsafe regions of code? I'm guessing this isn't possible unless that arbitrary object itself has synchronized methods to protect its own state, correct?

Comment: If you returned an object from the Get method that is and should be protected then you will be in trouble. Good design will insure that you do not simply "leak" (return) things from inside a method that should be protected. Because then the caller is open to manipulate this object. Now you have two pieces of code that can change this object, and only one is protected. Your code is no longer thread safe.

Answer (score 2):

1) Yes

2) That's a deadlock

3) The parts of your code you want to block are an implementation detail of your class.  Exposing the lock object by using `lock(this)` or `lock(this.GetType())` is asking for trouble since now external code can lock the same object and block your code unintentionally or maliciously.  The lock object should be private.

4) It isn't very clear what you mean, you certainly wouldn't want to expose the Hashtable directly.  Just keep it as a private field of the class, encapsulating it.

However, the odds that you can safely expose your class to client code using threads go down very rapidly with the number of public methods and properties you expose.  You'll quickly get to a point where only the client code can properly take a lock.  Fine-grained locking creates lots of opportunities for threading races when the client code is holding on to property values.  Say a Count property value you return.  By the time it *uses* the value, like in a for loop, the Count property might have changed.  Only the most careful design can avoid these traps, a serious headache.

Furthermore, fine-grained locking is very inefficient since it inevitably is done in the most inner parts of your code.  Locks are not *that* expensive, a rough 100 cpu cycles, but it quickly adds up.  Especially wasted effort if the class object isn't actually used in multiple threads.

You then have no option but to declare your class thread-unsafe and the client code needs to use it in a thread-safe manner.  Also the core reason that so many .NET classes are not thread-safe.  This is the biggest reason that threading is so hard to get right, the programmer least likely to do it correctly is responsible for doing the most difficult thing.